# I created 2 data frame and I tried to merge it. But it shows an error: "Error in fix.by(by.x, x) : 'by' must specify a uniquely valid column"

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

```
student<-data.frame("Roll_No"=c("202","203","204","205","206","157"),"First_Name"=c("Shahrukh","Shakti","Shantanu","Shashank","Shirke","Abhinav"),"Last_Name"=c("Khan","Rawat","Verma","Sinha","Ganesh","MIshra"),"State"=c("MP","MP","UT","UP","Maharashtra","MP"))

elec<-data.frame("Roll"=c("202","203","204","205","206","157"),"Subjects"=c("Operations","Operations","Operations","Analytics","Marketing","Marketing"))
print(student)
print(elec)

kpv <- merge(student,elec,by.x = c("ROll_No"),by.y = c("ROll"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Be careful of case-sensitive nature of variable names. Here, I adjusted them in your merge call:

```
student<-data.frame("Roll_No"=c("202","203","204","205","206","157"),"First_Name"=c("Shahrukh","Shakti","Shantanu","Shashank","Shirke","Abhinav"),"Last_Name"=c("Khan","Rawat","Verma","Sinha","Ganesh","MIshra"),"State"=c("MP","MP","UT","UP","Maharashtra","MP"))

elec<-data.frame("Roll"=c("202","203","204","205","206","157"),"Subjects"=c("Operations","Operations","Operations","Analytics","Marketing","Marketing")) 

print(student)
print(elec)

kpv <- merge(student,elec,by.x = c("Roll_No"),by.y = c("Roll"))
kpv
```